# Function that only runs when matrices has NAs in it

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices, one of them has a NA value and I want to use a function that only runs if there are `NA`s present in the data, so if I run the function it should only work on `df2` and not `df1`. How would I do this?

```
df1 <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
df2 <- matrix(1,2,3,NA, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: You can create a function with `if(all(!is.na(obj))) yourfun(obj)` or it should be the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment above, here is a complete answer (assuming I understand what you are getting at).  The function is set up to do something or not to the matrix depending on whether it has NA values.

```
df1 <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
df2 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,NA), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)


myfunc <- function(m) {

  ret <- m  
  
  if (all(!is.na(m))) {
   
    print("This matrix has no NAs") 
   
  } else {
   
    print("This matrix has NAs")
  
  }
   
  return(ret)
  
}


myfunc(df1)
# [1] "This matrix has no NAs"
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4

myfunc(df2)
# [1] "This matrix has NAs"
#       [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2   NA
```